# Differences between m/PATTERN/ and /PATTERN/ in perl

Tags: regex, perl, match

Is there any technical difference between the following code segments in perl?  They seem to behave identical

```
my $str = "A cat is red";

if($str =~ /cat/) {
    print "Matches\n";
}
```

vs

```
my $str = "A cat is red";

if($str =~ m/cat/) {
    print "Matches\n";
}
```

The difference in this code is the "m" on line 3.  Why would someone omit or not omit the "m"?

Comment: Its to help the parser, Possibly when the delimeter changes to something other than /, or the =~ operator is not used, and syntax is ambiguous. (but I'm no Perl expert)

Comment: For example `@array = m/(\w+)/g;` which might be a common usage.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See the [RegExp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) documentation: they're identical. The `m` "version" allows you to use other characters instead of `/` as a separator. But apart from that, no difference.

Comment: Also, my preference is to use the m version to be consistent with similar notations i.e. `m//`, `s///`, `tr//`, `qr//`, `qw//`, `q//`, `qq//` etc. I find consistency easier on the eyes when reading back code.

Comment: Lastly, instead of /'s, I commonly use #'s, since they aren't characters I often need to use within, therefore less "untidy" escaping necessary i.e. `m##`.

Comment: @Chris, I find that awful. It makes qw look like s///. I purposefully don't use `/` as delimiter except for regex operators and `tr`. Consistency between different things is a *bad* thing. Different things should look different.

Comment: @Chris, I'd rather encourage comments in regex patters than prevent them from existing! `#` makes for a bad regex delimiter.

Comment: @ikegami My personal preferences are as above, and work best for me. I beg to differ with regards to consistency across sizable code, but I agree with encouraging comments in regex patterns. I tend to write scenario tests, and instead comment these, I should do both.

Comment: @Chris, You make it sound like I oppose consistency, while it's quite the opposite. consistency is *extremely* important. Similar things should look similar. It's *disguising* I'm against. Different things should look different.

Comment: @ikegami Consistency in context of what we were discussing. Functions perform different things, but we will usually call them in the same way. It is their namespace which is most important, just like the m or the s or the tr etc. After all, they are all grouped under `quote and quote-like operators`. I honestly understand your point, and the differences between operators, but I prefer my style. I wonder if Perl Best Practices mentions this.

Comment: @Chris, Re "will usually call them in the same way." Not even close! Even within the subset of operators known as functions, there are variances. `map` and `grep` are particularly unique and are called particularly differently. And when you look at operators as a whole, the printing operator is called very differently than addition. There's a good reason for that. The same reason that `+` is used instead of `add` applies to using `"` instead of `/` for double-quoted strings. It's key to readability to be able differentiate the two quickly. You're the first I've ever heard to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Chris, PBP is the opinion of one person, and has a number of practices generally considered not just poor but bad. I think tchrist advocates for always using `q` and `qq` (a poor practice noone used, that just adds noise, and that hides information), but as far as I know, he didn't suggest always using `/` as the delimiter. Like I said, you're the first I've seen suggest this.

Comment: @ikegami Usually, not always. With regards to `grep` and `map`, if I could write it i.e. `grep( sub { }, @list );` I would. "It's key to readability to be able differentiate the two quickly", this was my original point, this is the purpose of my style, it is my preference. My editor uniformly highlights the groups of quote and quote-like operation, which my eyes easily separate based on the namespace at the beginning of each notation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44182/discussion-between-chris-and-ikegami)

Answer (score 11):

There is no difference.

`/.../` is short for `m/.../`, just like `'...'` is short for `q'...'`, and `"..."` is short for `qq"..."`.

If you're going to use the default delimiter (`/` for regex match, `'` for single-quoted string literals, and `"` for double-quoted string literals), you can omit the leading letter(s).

Specifying the leading letter(s) allows you to change the delimiter.

```
/.../      m/.../     m!...!     m{...}        Match operator
'...'      q'...'     q!...!     q{...}        Single-quoted string literal
"..."      qq"..."    qq!...!    qq{...}       Double-quoted string literal
```

This can be useful to reduce escaping. For example,

```
/^http:\/\//
```

is clearer when written as

```
m{^http://}
```

Otherwise, the "m", "q" or "qq" is usually omitted. "s", "tr" and "qw" are not optional.

All of this is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).