# Why use different separators (/ , |) in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I found this code in a Perl script:

```
$var =~ s,/$,,;
```

It seems to be a regex pattern, but I was expecting to find "/" (or "|") instead of "," as separator.

When and why should one use "/" or "|" or "," in a regex pattern?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733602/differences-between-m-pattern-and-pattern-in-perl/20735252#20735252

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Perl, in the substitution operator, as well as many other operators, you can substitute the delimiter for almost any punctuation character, such as

```
s#/$##
s=/$==
s!/$!!
```

Which one to use when is a matter of what you need at the time. Preferably you choose a delimiter that does not conflict with the characters in your regex, and one that is readable.

In your case, a different delimiter from `/` was used because one wanted to include a slash in the regex, to remove a trailing slash. With the default delimiters, it would have been:

```
s/\/$//
```

Which is not as easy to read.

Like I mentioned above, you can do this with a great many operators and functions:

```
m#...#
qw/.../
qw#...#
tr;...;;
qq?...?
```

Comment: not just punctuation characters: letters work too: `"foo" =~ s ofoor` → `oo`. However, there is no justification to ever do this (obfuscation aside).

Comment: @amon Indeed. I seem to recall someone using space once, but can't recall how. But perhaps not something to recommend.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, the default regular expression delimiter is `/`.

However, other characters may be used instead of `/`.  Typically, you would use alternate delimiters when the regular expression itself includes a `/`.  Using alternate delimiters avoids excessive escaping of the delimiter:

```
s/foo\/bar\//baz/;
```

vs.

```
s|foo/bar/|baz|;
```

[perlpdoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> This is particularly useful for matching path names that contain "/",
>   to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome).