# matching cond in perl using double exclaimation

Tags: regex, perl, match

```
if ($a =~ m!^$var/!)
```

`$var` is a key in a two dimensional hash and `$a` is a key in another hash.

What is the meaning of this expressions?

Comment: @zdim Just write this as answere would be nice.

Comment: @AndyA. Sure, if you feel that that's appropriate, posted...

Comment: Should be `if ($a =~ m!^\Q$var\E/!)`. As-is, it suffers from a [code-injection bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) because the value of `$var` is mistakenly treated as a regex pattern. \Q\E causes the value to be converted into a regex pattern that matches the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use different separators (/ , |) in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335765/how-to-use-different-separators-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) ("regex"), where the `!` character is used as the delimiter for the pattern that is to be matched in the string that it binds to via the [`=~` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) (the `$a`<sup>†</sup>  here).

It may clear it up to consider the same regex with the usual delimiter instead, `$a =~ /^$var\//` (then `m` may be omitted); but now any `/` used in the pattern clearly must be escaped.  To avoid that unsightly and noisy `\/` combo one often uses another character for the delimiter, as nearly any character may be used (my favorite is the curlies, `m{^$var/}`). <sup>‡</sup> <sup>§</sup>

This regex in the question tests whether the value in the variable `$a` begins with (by [`^` anchor](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Metacharacters)) the value of the variable `$var` followed by `/` (variables are evaluated and the result used). <sup>§</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> Not a good choice for a variable name since `$a` and `$b` are used by the builtin `sort`

<sup>‡</sup> With the pattern prepared ahead of time the delimiter isn't even needed

```
my $re = qr{^$var/};

if ($string =~ $re) ...
```

(but I do like to still use `//` then, finding it clearer altogether)

Above I use [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qr/STRING/msixpodualn) but a simple `q()` would work just fine (while I absolutely recommend `qr`). These take nearly any characters for the delimiter, as well.

---

<sup>§</sup>  Inside a pattern the evaluated variables are used as regex patterns, what is wrong in general (when this is intended they should be compiled using `qr` and thus used as subpatterns).

An unimaginative example: a variable `$var = q(\s)` (literal backslash followed by letter `s`) evaluated inside a pattern yields the `\s` sequence which is then treated as a regex pattern, for whitespace. (Presumably unintended; we just wanted `\` and `s`.)

This is remedied by using [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta), `/\Q$var\E/`, so that possible metacharacters in `$var` are escaped; this results in the correct pattern for the literal characters, `\\s`. So a correct way to write the pattern is `m{^\Q$var\E/}`.

Failure to do this also allows the injection bug.  Thanks to ikegami for commenting on this.

Comment: :) - (But I don't like the curlies because of the quantifier.)

Comment: @AndyA. Alright :)  You mean that it hurts readability?  (Can still use it -- `m{ (.{3}) }x` ...)

Comment: OK - works as `m{.{3}}` too. And the `{}` quantifiers not seen often, so may be best. TIMTOWTDI

Comment: @AndyA. Right, that's what I meant -- the curlies nest (pardon my `()` in the example, accidental remainder for some curious edge-case tests I ran). Absolutely a matter of taste, agreed (except for nesting, which is a factual advantage over the single-char delims)

Answer (score 1):

The match operator (`m/.../`) is one of Perl's "quote-like" operators. The standard usage is to use slashes before and after the regex that goes in the middle of the operator (and if you use slashes, then you can omit the `m` from the start of the operator). But if the regex itself contains a slash then it is convenient to use a different delimiter instead to avoid having to escape the embedded slash. In your example, the author has decided to use exclamation marks, but any non-whitespace character can be used.

Many Perl operators work like this - `m/.../`, `s/.../.../`, `tr/.../.../`, `q/.../`, `qq/.../`, `qr/.../`, `qw/.../`, `qx/.../` (I've probably forgotten some).